# Setting a value in a QTP webElement but it doesn't remain after leaving the page

Tags: qtp, qwebelement

I have a droplist which QTP is recognizing as a webElement.  I have found several ways to set the value in this webElement but once I go to another page in my app and then return to the main page, the value in the webElement is no longer there.  I'm using...

```
Browser("Policy Add").Page("Policy Add").WebTable("Transaction Effective").WebElement("dbo").Object.innertext= "Cash Refund"

set oEdit = Browser("Policy Add").Page("Policy Add").WebElement("dbo")
oEdit.Object.innerHTML = "Cash Refund"
```

I have seen several articles about using the FireEvent, but I don't understand how this works.  Do I set the value in the webElement with one of the above commands and then fire and event or do you specify the fire event and then it occurs automatically when you do one of the options like "onchange".

I have searched everything I can think of and tried everything I can think of and still have a problem.  I have checked the HP - QTP Knowledge Base and can't find anything there either.

Answer (score 0):

Answer here
http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/qtp/how-to/web/how-to-set-text-in-a-webelement-or-frame/

I checked **Method 2** for Chrome and it works correct

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of issue to enter data in to a weblement. Below code helped me to resolve the issue.

```
set oEdit = Browser("Policy Add").Page("Policy Add").WebElement("dbo")
oEdit.object.focus
ooEdit.object.click
set objWshell=createobject("wscript.shell")
objWshell.sendkeys "text to enter"
set objWshell=nothing
```